# MIPS program not giving the right output

Tags: loops, assembly, mips

I am writing a program to take 10 numbers from user into .word. The program is:

```
.data
msg1: .asciiz"Ener the number: "

fibs: .word 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
.text

main:
li $t0, 0

loop:  # (loop condition, TODO)
bgt $t0,9 ,exit
li $t1, 0 # i = 0

la $a0,msg1 # display prompt string
li $v0,4
syscall
li $v0,5 # read 1st integer into $t0
syscall
move $t2,$v0
lw $t2, fibs($t1) # fib = fibs[i]
addi $t1, $t1, 4 # i++ <= +4
j loop
exit:
move $a0,$t1 # output sum
li $v0,1
syscall
li $v0, 10 # exit the program
syscall
```

However, the loop never ends and continuously takes the input...I want it to stop and show me the numbers I have input after the 10 integers are entered

Comment: You forgot to increment `$t0`. Learn to use the debugger.

Comment: I added the following line at the end of loop: 
addi $t0, $t0, 1 , it still continuously takes input

Comment: _"it still continuously takes input"_. It exits after 10 iterations for me. Perhaps youy added the instruction at the wrong place, or forgot to save the file.

Comment: It works now, I forgot to save the file! Thanks !